# How can I load RDF\XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question about using OWL file that is built with RDF\XML in Protege software. I don't know how can I load and query(using SPARQL) this OWL file in c#. And I want to used it in my project.
Thanks for your attention.
Your sincerely,
Myat Wutyi Phyo

Comment: The file can be treated like any xml file.  This is a very broad question since there are a lot of tags in an owl file and without seeing the exact elements that you are looking for I can't answer the question.  Please post the exact portion of the xml you want to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an API. Try dotNetRDF or OWL API.